# reCAPTCHA form is returning an error

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I have a simple Recaptcha included in my form, and it's giving me this error: `Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success'`

I've looked at the documentation, and I've included all the necessary components of the integration. When I submit my form I still receive the same error.

Thanks for the help! :)

Here's my code:

PHP:

```
// reCAPTCHA
$captcha = isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) ? $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] : "";

if (empty($captcha)) {
    echo "Please check the reCAPTCHA.";
}
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=removed_for_demonstration&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($response.success == true) {
    echo "It worked";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="removed_for_demonstration"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="contact" value="SUBMIT GAME" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's reCaptcha response is a JSON Object. You need to decode the response with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) if you want to access the values like in an array.

```
$decoded_response = json_decode($response, true)
if ($decoded_response["success"] == true) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Edit:

You can also access the data OOP-Style:

```
$decoded_response = json_decode($response)
if ($decoded_response->success) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :D I did a tutorial on YouTube, and the guy used the method I used and it didn't end up working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change

```
if ($response.success == true) {
```

To:

```
if ($response ['success']) == true) {
```